# SQL, how to retrieve a count based on a substring

Tags: sql

I need to split out an lsd on a well location.
typically this is what it looks like 100/1-27-94-7w4m
I need to grab a count of anything that is w4, w5, w6
that would be alberta
anything that is w3 , w2,w1 or anything then the other would be sask.

how can I parse a string to get that count...
select count(*) from tblWell
substring, charindex...? examples would be nice

Comment: put some sample data, table structure and required output, so we can understand your problem.
and are you using MS SQL Server??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do something like this:

```
select which, count(*)
from (select 'w4' as code, 'alberta' as which union all
      select 'w5' as code, 'alberta' as which union all
      select 'w6' as code, 'alberta' as which union all
      select 'w1' as code, 'sask' as which union all
      select 'w2' as code, 'sask' as which union all
      select 'w3' as code, 'sask' as which
     ) lookup join
     table t
     on t.column = '%'+lookup.which+'%'
group by which;
```